# Skipping multiple numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to use Regex for a project I am doing for work.
I have a set of numbers that looks like this:

```
23    14    62  -121    98   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
24    13    64  -118   101   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    10    65  -124    93   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    11    62  -130    93   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16     2    65  -127    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18     1    68  -127    86   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
29    -1    64  -129    92   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
22     2    63  -131    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16    13    62  -130    91   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
15     6    66  -131    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16     2    62  -137    80   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16    -5    63  -133    74   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
24    -1    60  -135    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
15    11    59  -137    86   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
11     8    64  -131    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    10    64  -130    92   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
20    11    65  -136    96   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
20     8    59  -136    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18    13    59  -135    90   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18    10    60  -138    88   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
23     6    60  -133    88   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
20    10    57  -127    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
23     4    61  -127    88   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
14    -3    63  -131    75   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16    -5    62  -129    73   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
25    -6    62  -127    80   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
21     2    60  -129    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
14     3    65  -133    81   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
14     8    64  -132    86   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    11    59  -131    89   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
28     5    59  -129    93   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
29    -3    56  -130    82   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
24     0    58  -128    82   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
28    12    65  -128   104   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
25     4    65  -123    94   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
17    -1    61  -126    77   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18     2    62  -130    82   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
```

I want to get the 10th number in each row (165) with only one or two regex statements. The number changes occasionally from 165 so that I am not able to hard code it.
So far I have:

```
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
```

Which is obviously not 1 or 2 steps it's 10 plus it gives me 9 points I don't want.
Is there a way to get this in only 1 or 2 statements?

Comment: Why are your regexes so specific, rather than, say, `\S+` or `[-+]?\d+` for each number? Actually, why even use regexes?

Comment: Consider splitting each line on whitespace and then accessing the 10th element. If you say what language you're using, we can help the syntax.

Comment: If the 10th number was always 165, the solution would be INCREDIBLY easy :)

Comment: Why don't you simply do `awk '{ print $10 }' file`?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm using a program that only allows regex

Comment: @Austin, if your first question was answered you should give credit where credit is due and start another question.  That other guy was quick to suggest you delete your other question and start a new question here.  If your questions are unrelated, even on the same data, you should ask two different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the columns in all the rows are a fixed width, you could just do this:

```
^.{55}(\d+)
```

Note this is designed to match numbers like "165" with no sign or fractional component. This might be more flexible:

```
^.{55}([+-]?\d+(?:.\d+)?)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: If you don't have to use regex, but can use Awk for example, you can make it much simpler:

```
cat file.dat | awk '{print $10}'
```

---

Here's my variation:

```
^(?:[\S-\.]+\s+){9}(\S+)
```

Your number (i.e. 165) will be then stored in the first capture group (i.e. `$1`, depending on the language you're using).

Explained:

```
^             // Beginning of the line
(?:           // Do not capture this group (we're not interested in it)
  \S+         //   Any non-space character - one or more times
  \s+         //   Followed by a white-space character (one or more)
){9}          // Repeat the above nine times
(\S+)         // Any non-white space characters (our tenth number)
```

Usage example in Perl:

```
cat file.dat | perl -ne 'print $1 if s/(?:\S+\s+){9}(\S+)//'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

Or, even better (thanks, @SamIAm!):

```
^(\S+\s+){9}(\S+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with this regex

```
/^.*?(?:[\d\.]+[^\d\.]+?){9}([\d\.-]+)/
```

http://rubular.com/r/0cwhaL92aw

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what language/tools you're using, so here's a Java example:

```
// Split the input into each row:
final String rows[ ] = INPUT.split( "\\n" );

// Iterate through each row:
for ( final String row : rows )
{
  // Split the row into components separated by spaces:
  final String components[ ] = row.split( "\\s+" );

  assert components.length < 9 : "There is no 10th number!";

  final double number = Double.parseDouble( components[ 9 ] );
}
```