# Skipping multiple numbers (not hard coded)

Tags: regex

I am trying to use Regex for a project I am doing for work.
I have a set of numbers that looks like this:

```
23    14    62  -121    98   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
24    13    64  -118   101   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    10    65  -124    93   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    11    62  -130    93   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16     2    65  -127    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18     1    68  -127    86   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
29    -1    64  -129    92   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
22     2    63  -131    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16    13    62  -130    91   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
15     6    66  -131    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16     2    62  -137    80   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16    -5    63  -133    74   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
24    -1    60  -135    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
15    11    59  -137    86   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
11     8    64  -131    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    10    64  -130    92   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
20    11    65  -136    96   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
20     8    59  -136    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18    13    59  -135    90   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18    10    60  -138    88   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
23     6    60  -133    88   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
20    10    57  -127    87   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
23     4    61  -127    88   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
14    -3    63  -131    75   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
16    -5    62  -129    73   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
25    -6    62  -127    80   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
21     2    60  -129    83   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
14     3    65  -133    81   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
14     8    64  -132    86   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
19    11    59  -131    89   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
28     5    59  -129    93   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
29    -3    56  -130    82   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
24     0    58  -128    82   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
28    12    65  -128   104   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
25     4    65  -123    94   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
17    -1    61  -126    77   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
18     2    62  -130    82   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 165 60.00 .... ...
```

I want to get the 10th number in each row (165) with only one or two regex statements. The number changes occasionally from 165 so that I am not able to hard code it.
So far I have:

```
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,5})|([+-]{0,1}[.]{1,1}(?=[0-9])[0-9]{0,5}))
([+-]{0,1}[0-9]{1,5})
```

Which is obviously not 1 or 2 steps it's 10 plus it gives me 9 points I don't want.

This problem has been fixed but now a new problem has arisen:

I thought that:

```
(?#<INS:5>)
^.{53}([+-]?\d+)
\.\.\.\. \.\.\.
(?#<INS:5>)
^.{53}([+-]?\d+)
\.\.\.\. \.\.\.
(?#<INS:5>)
^.{53}([+-]?\d+)
\.\.\.\. \.\.\.
```

fixed my problem but it turns out this code breaks in the following situation:

```
  9486     9    68  -133  9562   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 106 60.00 .... ...
  9455     3    63  -129  9521   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 106 60.00 .... ...
  9417     3    64  -132  9485   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  9367     3    60  -129  9431   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  9305    12    56  -131  9373   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  9237    12    66  -135  9315   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  9170     2    65  -129  9238   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  9111     4    62  -127  9177   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  9041    -0    58  -126  9099   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  8969     6    57  -129  9032   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  89 60.00 .... ...
  8887     9    60  -132  8956   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  73 60.00 .... ...
  8802     5    62  -131  8869   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  73 60.00 .... ...
  8720     1    64  -132  8785   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  73 60.00 .... ...
  8634     9    66  -137  8710   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2  73 60.00 .... ...
```

When the 10th number drops below 100 the code fails. Is there any way to make this where it would not break for 10's and 1's?

Comment: Please specify the language because the answer will vary.

Comment: `awk '{print $10}' file` would do it on Linux

Comment: Please delete this question and continue on your previous question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping multiple numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645354/skipping-multiple-numbers)

Comment: @leppie, This is not a repeat. It is a different issue I'm having

Comment: @jmstoker I am using SEL acSELerator RTAC software. There is not really a language, just it's own set of commands (plus there's no tag for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `[ ]*` to the regex.  This should grab 106 or 89.  All it does is grabs an extra space if it exists before the number.

```
(?#<INS:5>)
^.{53}[ ]*([+-]?\d+)
\.\.\.\. \.\.\.
(?#<INS:5>)
^.{53}[ ]*([+-]?\d+)
\.\.\.\. \.\.\.
(?#<INS:5>)
^.{53}[ ]*([+-]?\d+)
\.\.\.\. \.\.\.
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, just using one string as an example.

```
   var someString="9486     9    68  -133  9562   -0.0   -0.1    0.0   -0.2 106 60.00 0909";
   var getum =someString.match(/[\-\+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g);
   getnum[9] // gives 106
```

note: using javascript